# Microsoft Authenticode Code Signing ( EV ) + Google Cloud HSM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, code-signing, hsm

Our company uses EV codesigning certificate on eToken usb dongle, but we are currently planning to move our build and signing procedures to virtual server in cloud, everything is fine, except one thing, it is codesigning process, GlobalSign allows certificates to be stored either on usb dongle or HSM. I think HSM will do the job, can somebody advise best practice for cloud HSM? I found, that google cloud offers [Google Cloud HSM](https://cloud.google.com/hsm/) but how to connect `signtool.exe` with this service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind using another signing tool, [Jsign](https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/) supports Google Cloud HSM out of the box (no PKCS#11 module is required):

```
jsign --storetype GOOGLECLOUD --storepass <api-access-token> \
      --keystore projects/first-rain-123/locations/global/keyRings/mykeyring \
      --alias test --certfile full-chain.pem application.exe
```

(disclaimer: I'm the main author of this open source project)

The difficult part is to get GlobalSign to issue a certificate for the private key stored in Google Cloud HSM (this typically involves an audit process to certify the key was properly generated by an HSM, or providing an [attestation certificate](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/attest-key)).

Comment: Hello! I am actually trying to use your tool but it tells me "Signature verification failed, the private key doesn't match the certificate". What I have done is to generate a key within GCP HSM, then generate a CSR using this key. I have fed this CSR to Digicert and they have given me a pem which is what I use for jsign. However, their UI do not ask for attestation certificate or anything like that. Do you have any clue? Thank you in advance and regards

Comment: Others have reported similar issues, that might be a problem with the padding of the key, or with the order of the certificate chain, see https://github.com/ebourg/jsign/issues/93

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, I have written in the issue to see if someone gives me a hint because I have not managed to solve it and the order of certificates seems good to me so I am not sure what else could be done to try to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to follow the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/hsm#kms-create-key-ring-gcloud) to create an HSM-backed key in Google Cloud KMS:

```
gcloud kms keys create ${KEY_NAME} \
    --keyring ${KEY_RING} \
    --location ${LOCATION} \
    --purpose "encryption" \
    --protection-level "hsm"
```

Then you can use [this PKCS #11 module](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/pkcs11-library) - recently released by Google - along any tool that supports this API, like [osslsigncode](https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode):

```
osslsigncode sign \
    -pkcs11engine /path/to/system/pkcs11.so \
    -pkcs11module google-kms-pkcs11-module.so \
    -cert certificate.crt \
    -key "pkcs11:token=${KEY_NAME};object=key" \
    -n "Your App Name" -in yourapp.exe -out yourapp-signed.exe
```

Haven't tested this command yet but, from my experience, osslsigncode works pretty well with [pkcs11-proxy](https://github.com/iksaif/pkcs11-proxy), which is another PKCS #11 module used for EV code signing using a token plugged on another machine over the network.

Despite the commands above being written using "Linux syntax", both osslsigncode and Google KMS module also release pre-compiled windows binaries on GitHub.

Answer (score -5):

There is not currently a way to do this. If you have your EV cert on a physical dongle, you will need to set up a physical build agent on your local network to handle the signing portion of the build.

Comment: Different environments have different needs. In many cases this _is_ a large burden, even for released code.